# Mysql query to sum rows and columns based on column criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help me with writing a query for the following condition. I have a table which I have listed below

```
ID  Wt1  Wt1_Type  Wt2  Wt2_Type  Wt3   Wt3_Type  Wt4  Wt4_Type
--------------------------------------------------------------
1   200  1         220  1         300   2         400  3    
2   100  4         150  3         100   5         120  1  
3   100  3         110  1         200   5         100  4
```

I want a query to sum all the the weights (wt1, wt2, wt3, wt4) grouped on the weight type (wt1_type, wt2_type, wt3_type, wt4_type).

The output should look like

```
Wt_type   Total
1         650
2         300
3         650
4         200
5         300
```

Can someone please help me draft a mysql query to get this result ?

Thanks

Comment: what is your dbms?

Comment: The database is mysql

Comment: This is a terrible table design.  Why do you have four separate columns which logically store the same thing?

Comment: I agree, this could be normalized to be a part of another transaction table. The design was a compromise between table lookups and simplicity which has impact on other aspects of what the table is being used for. I just posted a small part of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below - using union all and subquery

```
select Wt_Type,sum(Wt) as total from
(
   select Wt1_Type as Wt_Type,Wt1 as Wt from tablename
   union all
   select Wt2_Type ,Wt2 from tablename
   union all
   select Wt3_Type ,Wt3 from tablename
   union all
   select Wt4_Type ,Wt4 from tablename
)A group by Wt_Type
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than giving the answer by @fa06, which should work for you, I am going to suggest using a better table design.  Here is how you should be storing your data:

```
ID  Type Wt
-------------
1   1    200
2   4    100
3   3    100
4   1    220
5   3    150
6   1    110
7   2    300
8   5    100
9   5    200
10  3    400
11  1    120
12  4    100
```

Note that there is a single column which stores the type and a single column for that type's weight.  Now your expected output just requires a very simple query:

```
SELECT Type, SUM(Wt) AS Total
FROM yourTableUpdated
GROUP BY Type;
```

Databases are really good at performing operations across rows, much less so across columns.

Comment: Yes, I agree and accept what you have proposed. The table has some other table id specific fields that I omitted. Hence ideally this table should have been split into 2, the one that has the id specific and another one like you have proposed to capture the weights. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Use this it should be work**

```
select Wt_Type,sum(Wt) as total from ( select Wt1_Type as Wt_Type,Wt1 as Wt from tablename union all select Wt2_Type ,Wt2 from tablename union all select Wt3_Type ,Wt3 from tablename union all select Wt4_Type ,Wt4 from tablename )A group by Wt_Type
```